# What means %%~za %%~nxa, is they default variables in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi im looking for some help with my batch file for sorting the files by file size and when they were created and i find a script like this

```
for %%a in (C:\Users\subhamt\Downloads\embeddedsection.zip) do set var=%%~za
```

in this case is `%%~za` the filesize of the `embeddedsection.zip`, but i don't find any reference to this and don't know how to work with it, if i don't want to set var as a filesize but as a date for example

i know the `%%~nxa` took the filename. can i found somewhere the others?
Thx for help

Comment: Run the command `for /?` for more information about those. Also, I would recommend switching to PowerShell.

Comment: You can also find the meanings at [ss64](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: Batch files can't sort numerically, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552725/sorting-files-by-numerical-order.

Comment: "can i found somewhere the others?" -  `for /?`

Comment: ... but for sorting by size, best use the `dir` command: `dir /os` or `dir /o-s`