# How to sort lines in text file using batch file?

Tags: sorting, batch-file

How to sort by line on my text file?

For example, I have a file named a.txt with 4 lines:

```
DATE,EVENT,TYPE, 
2016-07-01 14:43:17,Communication lost,UPS external event 
2016-07-01 14:38:59,UPS power on immediately,UPS external event 
2016-07-01 14:38:04,AC recovery,Input event
```

I want to attempt on another file, but on another file, the line must be sorted by datetime. The new datetime is on the last line and Date, Event, Type still on the first line.

Comment: This describes how to sort a file in windows from the command line. http://superuser.com/questions/332268/windows-7-sorting-contents-of-a-file/332269?

Comment: See my answer here. This allows you to sort on date/time unlike the inbuilt `sort`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552725/sorting-files-by-numerical-order

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
REM get first line:
<a.txt set /p first=
REM write it to a new file:
>b.txt echo %first%
REM sort the rest and append to the new file:
<a.txt more +1|sort >>b.txt
```

NOTE: `sort` sorts strings, not dates. So this does only work because
your date-format is YYYY-MM-DD