# cmd command to dump file list in numeric order

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Sorry I can't word this correctly but I need a command to create a text file that dumps the file names in numeric order. Here is the command that does what I want but everything that has 1 at the start is bunched, 2, 3 etc.....

```
(for %i in (*.flv) do @echo file '%i') > file.txt
```

Comment: Correct. Most commands from cmd.exe sort everything alpha-numerically. We have a little auxiliary batch file on Dostips that should help you. http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.SortTextWithNumbers

Comment: See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552725/sorting-files-by-numerical-order

Comment: What did you expect as output ? so [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40077559/edit) and add it like an example  !

Comment: @Squashman, you actually mean alphabetically, right? so that `file10` appears before `file2`, which is the standard behaviour of `dir`, `sort` and `set`, for example?

Answer (score 3):

Most `cmd`/batch file commands, like `dir`, `sort` and `set`, for instance, do pure alphabetic sorting, so any numeric parts are not treated particularly. For example, `string12` appears before `string3`, because the character `1` appears before `2` with the used way of sorting. To change the behaviour so that alpha-numeric sorting is applied, meaning that `string3` appears before `string12`, you have to write your own code for accomplishing that. The following script does exactly that, by padding every numeric part appearing in strings/file names to a fixed amount of digits, in which case alpha-numeric and alphabetic sort orders match. Below is the code, including explanatory remarks. As you can see, complex code is required to accomplish the task and to make the script secure against all characters that have special meanings to `cmd` (like  <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, `,`, `;`. `=` as well as `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `%`, `!`):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (temporary file used for sorting)
set /A "_DIGITS=12" & rem // (number of digits every numeric part is padded for sorting)

rem // Build string containing enough zeros for padding:
set "$PAD=" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%D in (1,1,%_DIGITS%) do set "$PAD=!$PAD!0"
endlocal & set "$PAD=%$PAD%"

rem // Prepare temporary file containing data to sort:
> "%_TEMPFILE%" (
    rem // Gather and resolve all command line arguments:
    for %%I in (%*) do (
        rem // Get pure file name:
        set "ITEM=%%~nxI"
        rem // Extend all numeric parts in file name to certain number of digits:
        call :PROCESS AUGM ITEM || >&2 echo ERROR: potential problem sorting "%%~nxI"!
        rem // Write extended and original file name into temporary file:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!AUGM!^|!ITEM!
        endlocal
    )
)

rem // Return content of temporary file in ascendingly sorted order:
for /F "tokens=2 delims=| eol=|" %%J in ('sort "%_TEMPFILE%"') do (
    rem // Simply return each item:
    echo(%%J
)

rem // Delete temporary file:
del "%_TEMPFILE%"

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS  rtn_augmented_string  ref_string
rem /* Routine to augment a string so that every numeric part is padded with leading
rem    zeros to the left to hold a predefined number of digits: */
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "#RTN=%~1"
set "#ARG=%~2"
rem // Initialise required variables:
set "COLL="
set "ERRL=0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%B in (^""!%#ARG%!"^") do (
    endlocal
    set "PSTR=%%~B"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
)
rem // Entry point for loop to handle one numeric string part:
:REPEAT
rem // Extract the string portions before and after the first numeric part:
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=0123456789 eol=0" %%A in ("+!PSTR!") do (
    endlocal
    set "PART=%%A"
    set "NEXT=%%B"
    rem // Determine length of string portion before first numeric part:
    call :LENGTH PLEN PART
    set /A "PLEN-=1"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "PART=!PART:~1!"
    rem // Split off string portion before first numeric part from total string:
    for %%C in (!PLEN!) do (
        if defined PSTR set "PSTR=!PSTR:~%%C!"
    )
    rem /* Splitt off string portion after first numeric part from remaining string;
    rem    this is nothing but extracting the first numeric part itself: */
    call :SPLIT PNUM NEXT PSTR
    rem // Determine the actual length of the numeric part:
    call :LENGTH NLEN PNUM
    rem // Do the actual padding with leading zeros of the numeric part:
    if defined PNUM (
        set "PNUM=%$PAD%!PNUM!"
        set "PNUM=!PNUM:~-%_DIGITS%!"
    )
    rem // Store the part after the first numeric part:
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%C in (^""!NEXT!"^") do (
        rem /* Build string with the string portion before the current numeric part
        rem    and the padded current numeric part itself: */
        for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%D in (^""!COLL!!PART!!PNUM!"^") do (
            rem // Check whether the predefined number of padding digits is sufficient:
            for /F %%E in ("!NLEN!") do (
                endlocal
                set "PSTR=%%~C"
                set "COLL=%%~D"
                if %%E GTR %_DIGITS% set "ERRL=1"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
    )
)
rem // Repeat the whole approach while there is still a remaining string portion:
if defined PSTR goto :REPEAT
rem // Return the string with padded numeric parts:
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%R in (^""!COLL!"^") do (
    endlocal
    endlocal
    set "%#RTN%=%%~R"
    exit /B %ERRL%
)
exit /B


:SPLIT  rtn_left_string  ref_split_char  val_string
rem /* Routine to split a string at the first occurrence of a certain character and to
rem    return the portion before it: */
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "#RTN=%~1"
set "#CHR=%~2"
set "#ARG=%~3"
rem // Initialise required variables:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "CHAR= " & if defined %#CHR% set "CHAR=!%#CHR%:~,1!"
if "!CHAR!"=="<" (set "PREF=>") else (set "PREF=<")
rem // Check whether a split character is defined:
if defined %#CHR% (
    rem /* Split character available, so split off first occurrence and everything after
    rem    from the original string: */
    for /F eol^=^%CHAR%^ delims^=^%CHAR% %%C in ("%PREF%!%#ARG%!") do (
        endlocal
        set "%#RTN%=%%C"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "%#RTN%=!%#RTN%:~1!"
    )
) else (
    rem // No split character defined, so do not split off anything:
    set "%#RTN%=!%#ARG%!"
)
rem // Return the resulting string:
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%R in (^""!%#RTN%!"^") do (
    endlocal
    endlocal
    set "%#RTN%=%%~R"
)
exit /B


:LENGTH  rtn_length  ref_string
rem /* Routine to determine the length of a given string: */
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "#RTN=%~1"
set "#ARG=%~2"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Check whether a string is provided:
if defined %#ARG% (
    rem // String is available, so calculate its length:
    set /A "%#RTN%=1"
    for %%A in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if not "!%#ARG%:~%%A!"=="" (
            set /A "%#RTN%+=%%A"
            set "%#ARG%=!%#ARG%:~%%A!"
        )
    )
) else (
    rem // String is empty, so length is zero:
    set /A "%#RTN%=0"
)
rem // Return the computed length:
for /F %%R in ("!%#RTN%!") do (
    endlocal
    endlocal
    set "%#RTN%=%%R"
)
exit /B
```

Provide (a) file pattern(s) as (a) command line argument(s), like this, for example (supposing the batch file is saved as `sort-alpha-num.bat`):

```dos
sort-alpha-num.bat "*.flv"
```

To store the resulting sorted list in a text file called `file.txt`, use this:

```dos
sort-alpha-num.bat "*.flv" > "file.txt"
```

In case an error message like `ERROR: potential problem sorting "1000000000000.flv"!` appears, increase the number of digits on top of the script (see line `set /A "_DIGITS=12"`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give us more information about how your output file should be ?

```dos
@echo off
set "folder=%userprofile%\Desktop\*.flv"
set "listfiles=listfiles.txt"
If Exist %listfiles% Del %listfiles%
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Rem Populate the array with existent files in this folder
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('Dir /s /b /a:-d "%folder%"') do (
    set /a Count+=1
    set "File[!Count!]=%%~na"
)
::******************************************************************
:Display_Files
cls & color 0B
echo(
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo %%i - !File[%%i]!
)
echo(
(
rem to save result into logfile
    For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo %%i - !File[%%i]!
    )
)>> %listfiles%
echo Hit any key to open %listfiles% :
Pause>nul & Start "" %listfiles%
```