# Sort lines by date (DD.MM.YYYY)

Tags: date, vbscript, text-files

Is there a possibility to sort lines within a textfile by date and save the results to another output file? Each line begins with a date (DD.MM.YYYY). Delimiter between date and text is Tab (no space). I prefer a solution in VBS.

*Source*

```
25.11.1968 Death of Upton Sinclair
14.06.1946 Birthday Donald Trump
25.11.2016 Death of Fidel Castro
14.06.1969 Birthday Steffi Graf
01.01.2017 New Year
```

to the new order *(target)*

```
01.01.2017 New Year
14.06.1946 Birthday Donald Trump
14.06.1969 Birthday Steffi Graf
25.11.1968 Death of Upton Sinclair
25.11.2016 Death of Fidel Castro
```

Order to change and compare: Month-Day-Year

Comment: *"I prefer a solution in VBS"* - Then you should write one. This site is not a code writing service.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552725/sorting-files-by-numerical-order

Comment: Okay, less snarky comment: Please read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and re-write your question accordingly. It is expected from you that you have tried to solve your task on your own (and that means beyond "I have searched and found nothing I could copy"). You should include the code you have written so far, along with a description of what the code is doing and what you expect instead. We are happy to help you learn. Not so happy to provide copy-and-paste snippets.

Comment: @Noodleslink looks like a good fit - don't be put off by the long code examples - just read to the bottom where there's a command line solution. Upvote to Noodles. Plus upvote for Tomalak for both the snarky comment and the less snarky comment.

Comment: Thanks @all, especially to Noodles for the hint.
I am still a beginner in VBS and English is not my home language (see my nickname). So expected some useful help to fulfil my expectations...
I tested Script.vbs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552725/sorting-files-by-numerical-order, but the Argument **d** doesn't work (extracts a time or date from the columns specified. Looks for the first date). I tried it with european date (DD-MM-YYYY) (DD.MM.YYYY) and with american one (MM.DD.YYYY). The Other arguments work fine.
Don't understand the block      ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "d" then

Comment: In English the `.` isn't a date or time separator. The script uses a regexp that is English specific. Alter the Regexp to include the `.`. The RegExp searches for the first sequence of numerals and `/`, `-`, and `:` then tries to assign to a variable in VBS using its conversion functions. VBS functions are locale aware.

Comment: `D` means sort descending.

Answer (score 0):

Here, it's not pretty and it doesn't sort in reverse order as you wanted, but hopefully this will teach you something if you learn like I do...

```
Option Explicit
Const fsoForReading = 1
Const fsoForWriting = 2

inputFile = "input.txt"
outputFile = "output.txt"

dim inputFile, outputFile, lineCount, file, fline, lDate, lYear, lMonth, lDay, iDate,output
dim a, d, i

dim objFSO, objFile

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'open up the file for reading
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(inputFile)
Set file = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(fsoForReading,-2)
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    fline = file.ReadLine               'get the line
    lDate = left(fline,10)              'get the date portion at the beginning (the first 10 characters)
    lYear = split(lDate,".")(2)     'parse the year from the date
    lMonth = split(lDate,".")(1)        'parse the month
    lDay= split(lDate,".")(0)           'parse the day

    iDate = lYear + lMonth + lDay       'put together the "index date".  The date needs to be formatted as yyyymmdd so it is sortable

    a.add iDate                             'add the index date to an array for easier sorting
    d.add iDate, fline                  'add the index date and line contents to a dictionary object

Loop                                            'go to the next line in the file

a.Sort()                                        'sort the array of dates
for each i in a                         'loop through the array of dates
    output = output + d(i) + vbCrlf 'add the appropriate dictionary object to the output
Next

call writeFile(output)                  'write the file
file.Close


WScript.Quit 0

sub writeFile(fc)
    dim fso
   'fn = fn + ".hl7"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if (fso.FileExists(outputFile)) then
        Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(outputFile,8,True)
        objFile.writeline fc
        objFile.Close  
    else
        Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile(outputFile,True)
        objFile.writeline fc
        objFile.Close  
    end if
end sub
```

Comment: For the downvoters, I don't answer questions only for the asker (?). This was a good challenge for me.  Plus, please remember not everyone learns the same.

Comment: Thanks for the lisitng, it looks good, but produces an error in line "This key is already associated with an element of this collection" (d.add iDate, fline).

Comment: hmm, hadn't thought about two lines having the same date.  I'm sure that's the issue.

Comment: Try changing the index to include `iDate` AND the entire line that way the sort will still work but the key should be unique.

Comment: I had to change this `iDate = lMonth + lDay + lYear` to get the desired sorting. To have unique dates I'd simply attach a random number

Comment: @LotPings that will not sort chronologically.

Comment: Look at his sample above, he wants to sort this way.

Comment: hrrm, he does have it actually sorted day, month, year but surely that's not what he intended... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯